# spark streaming from kafka on spark operator(Kubernetes)

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration, spark-operator

I have a spark structured streaming job in scala, reading from kafka and writing to S3 as hudi tables. Now I am trying to move this job to spark operator on EKS.

When I give the option in the yaml file.

```
spark.jars.packages: org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.1-bundle_2.12:0.11.1
```

But still I get the error at both the driver and executor

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchInputPartition .

How to add the package org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2, so it works.

Edit: Seems it is an existing issue fixed only in yet to be released version spark 3.4. Based on the suggestions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1132) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/352) I had to bake all the jars (spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2 and its dependencies and also hudi jar) into the spark image. Then it worked.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Make sure you use the same version for the spark-sql-kafka-0-10 JAR

Comment: The version on spark is also 3.1.2

Comment: Rather than in the YAML... In the code, can you put your `spark.jars.packages` there? Example - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb